# How to post with twitter API from client side

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-oauth, twitter-rest-api

I am looking for a method to let the user:

- sign in with twitter (I have setup this already)
- post a tweet from my website
- upon success, return the ID of the tweet

How can this be achieved?

The issue I see is that a user needs to setup a client id and so forth to automatize this (see: http://videlais.com/2015/02/28/how-to-create-a-basic-twitterbot-in-node-js-using-twit/)

Is there a way to bypass this by requesting the user one time read and write rights?

Comment: Please check the [ask] page for hints on how to improve your question.  You would need a [mcve] for us to help with troubleshooting.  How-to questions are not really highly voted here